# Display selected file in html input before upload

Tags: php, html, mysql, file, upload

How can i show file that i select thru browse field into html input? I want to see file that i selected before i press upload?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
          <input id="uploadFile" name="uploadFileOne" type="text" disabled="disabled" value="<?php echo $file_name; ?>" placeholder="EWIS" class="name-info-form file-witdth" />              
          <input class="upload" type="file" id="uploadOne" name="uploadOne" value="Select File"/ >
```

Comment: you are probably using some customized input field, because standard html input type='file' shows the selected file name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form>
  <input class="upload" type="file" id="uploadOne" name="uploadOne" onchange="setfilename(this.value);" value="Select File"/ >
  <input id="uploadFile" name="uploadFileOne" type="text" disabled="disabled" placeholder="EWIS" class="name-info-form file-witdth" />
</form>
```

remove `value=<?php echo $file_name; ?>` and use the javascript for set the name of file in textbox

```
<script>
  function setfilename(val)
  {
    var fileName = val.substr(val.lastIndexOf("\\")+1, val.length);
    document.getElementById("uploadFile").value = fileName;
  }
</script>
```

when you select the file using browse button, onchange event will fire and set the file name in text-box :)